# React, Yup, Formik. How to extend current schema from another schema

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

There are many schemes and they are combined by some identical fields. When changing the fields of one scheme, you need to change the same fields, but in other schemes. And I wanted the fields of different schemes, or the schemes themselves, to refer to or inherit one common scheme. Something like:

```
    import * as Yup from "yup";
    import {commonSchema} from "./common";

    export const parentSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      FirstName: Yup.string()
        .min(2, `Имя не может состоять менее чем из 2 сомволов`)
        .max(50, `Имя не может состоять более чем из 50 сомволов`)
        .required(`Поле 'Имя' обязательное для заполнения`),
      SecondName: ref(commonSchema.SecondName)
    });


    // commonSchema

    export const commonSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      SecondName: Yup.string()
        .min(2, `Отчество не может состоять менее чем из 2 сомволов`)
        .max(100, `Отчество не может состоять более чем из 100 сомволов`)
    });
```

In short, making changes to one general schema will not have to make changes to other schemas with the same fields.

I would like to collect all the common properties in one file. And then refer to the necessary properties from each file

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The closest thing to schema extension/inheritance in Yup is to use
`object.shape` to create a new schema based on existing schema:
[Yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema)

`object.shape(fields: object, noSortEdges?: Array<[string, string]>): Schema`

> Define the keys of the object and the schemas for said keys.
> Note that you can chain shape method, which acts like object extends

```js
const baseSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   id: string().isRequired(),  
  name: string().isRequired()
})

const someSchema = baseSchema.shape({
   id: number().isRequired(),
   age: number().isRequired()
})
```

which is equivalent to:

```js
const someSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   id: number().isRequired(), // notice how 'id' is overridden by child schema
   name: string().isRequired(),
   age: number().isRequired()
})
```

Another way is to use `concat(schema)` to create a new schema instance by combing two schemas:  [Yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedconcatschema-schema-schema)

> `mixed.concat(schema: Schema): Schema`
> Creates a new instance of the schema by combining two schemas. Only schemas of the same type can be concatenated.

```js
const baseSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   name: string().isRequired()
})

const someSchema = baseSchema.concat(
   Yup.object().shape({
    age: number().isRequired()
}))

// someSchema will be equipped with both `name` and `age` attributes
```

Please note that `concat` only works when two schema objects have different properties or same properties with exact same type.

Comment: because of bundle size import from yup what you need like import { object, string, array } from 'yup'. object({ name: blah }) instead of object().shape({ name: blah }) can be used. shape not worked in my case but concat did the job

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can do it:

```js
const CommonSchema = {
  firstName: Yup.string().required('First name is required')
};

const SchemaWithJustFirstName = Yup.object().shape({
  ...CommonSchema,
});

const SchemaWithSecondName = Yup.object().shape({
  ...CommonSchema,
  secondName: Yup.string().required('Second name is also required')
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's approach without Yup func. Has yup extend funct?